# Create a fake external sdcard storage space on android phone with no sd card slots

Tags: android, mount, partition, android-sdcard, parted

I was wondering if it would be possible to mount an extra custom partition as an external sdcard on an android phone.
I already know how to create extra partition on my phone's storage using parted (cuz i installed windows on my phone)

I think that creating such a fake sdcard slot could be possible this way, using parted to make the space and a script to mount it automatically, I just don't know how it would be done !

I'm interested in doing this because when you install custom roms you always end up wiping up userdata, so for phone where you have to store all of your photos and music on the internal storage this would get annoying very fast.

I haven't tried anything yet since my current phone has a real sd card slot, I'm just trying to know if I could replace it with a phone with no sd card slot